# Creating missing dummy indicator variable for a list of variable in a dataframe with specific values in python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset in pandas. For brevity, let's say I have the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [101,101,101,201,201,201,np.nan],
                  'col2':[123,123,124,np.nan,321,321,456],
                 'col3':['a',0.7,0.6,1.01,2,1,2],
                 'col4':['w',0.2,'b',0.7,'z',2,3],
                 'col5':[21,'z',0.3,2.3,0.8,'z',1.001],
                 'col6':[11.3,202.0,0.2,0.3,41.0,47,2],
                 'col7':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']})
```

[image: Initial Data]

Now I want to create categorical variables with the suffix `_missing` such that for any column in the dataset that contains missing `nan` a new column (variable) should be created that has values `1` for 'nan' values and `0` otherwise. For example, for `col1` and `col2`, their corresponding variables will be `col1_missing` and `col2_missing`.

Then for columns like `col3` that have alphabets in a column that is supposed to be numeric, I will like similar result as described above, but with the levels of categories increasing with the number of different alphabets. For example the new column corresponding to `col4` will be `col4_missing` and will contain 0 for non-alphabets, `1` for `b`, `2` for `w` and `3` for `z`. So the resulting frame should look as below:

[image: Resulting dataframe]

Is there any python function or package to do this? As a newbie, I am honestly overwhelmed with this and I would be grateful for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` the values from a dictionary:

```
def flag(s):
    flags = {'b': 1, 'w': 2, 'z': 3}
    return s.fillna('b').map(lambda x: flags.get(x, 0))

out = (pd
 .concat([df, df.apply(flag).add_suffix('_missing')], axis=1)
 .sort_index(axis=1)
 )
```

Output:

```
    col1  col1_missing   col2  col2_missing  col3  col3_missing col4  col4_missing   col5  col5_missing   col6  col6_missing col7  col7_missing
0  101.0             0  123.0             0     a             0    w             2     21             0   11.3             0    A             0
1  101.0             0  123.0             0   0.7             0  0.2             0      z             3  202.0             0    B             0
2  101.0             0  124.0             0   0.6             0    b             1    0.3             0    0.2             0    C             0
3  201.0             0    NaN             1  1.01             0  0.7             0    2.3             0    0.3             0    D             0
4  201.0             0  321.0             0     2             0    z             3    0.8             0   41.0             0    E             0
5  201.0             0  321.0             0     1             0    2             0      z             3   47.0             0    F             0
6    NaN             1  456.0             0     2             0    3             0  1.001             0    2.0             0    G             0
```

##### only columns with at least one non-zero

```
def flag(s):
    flags = {'b': 1, 'w': 2, 'z': 3}
    return s.fillna('b').map(lambda x: flags.get(x, 0))

# flag values 
df2 = df.apply(flag).add_suffix('_missing')

# keep only columns with at least one flag
df2 = df2.loc[:, df2.ne(0).any()]

out = (pd
 .concat([df, df2], axis=1)
 .sort_index(axis=1)
 )
```

Comment: mozway: This looks extremely helpful. Two things left to help me achieve my aim: 1.  'col6' and 'col7' should not be affected. 'Col7' is already character column and the entries there are correct categories. They are not missing categories.  Could a list of the FALSE  character columns be generated and parsed? 2. I feel 'z' in one column could take the value '1' if it is the only alphabet in that column among the floats or integers. But I can live with this second bit as it makes sense for 'z' to have the same meaning across the columns.

Comment: To ignore columns use: `df.drop(columns=['col6', 'col7']).apply(...)`. For the rest, it depends on what you want exactly ;)

Comment: I think with my large data, it will indeed be tedious to list the columns 6 and 7 types of columns to drop. Perhaps it would be helpful to implement a way of checking if a column has the suffix '''_missing''' and have '''0'''s through the entire column then they should be dropped.

Comment: Easy enough, see update

Comment: This is super great. And actually the keys in the flags dictionary should start from 'a'. One last thing: Can you help implement issue number 2 I raised in my first comment? That is the option where  if a columns has say only z as the alphabet, the corresponding missing column will render it 1. Similarly if say b and w are the only alphabets present, the missing column should render them 1 and 2, respectively? I would like to use test the two options in my analysis.